# textarea not expanding according to the content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using a `textarea` inside which i am getting some values from local db. The problem is the height of `textarea` is not resizing to the content available and rather its shrinked and only displaying one line.
I tried adding CSS but it doesn't seems to work. Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

`XSL`

```
<textarea id="post-text"><xsl:value-of select="$txn_desc"/></textarea>
```

`CSS`

```
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

Comment: You're going to need some frontend logic to achieve that. You can have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight).

Answer (score 1):

try adding

```
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden
}
```

and also make sure the parent html element have an appropriate height as well.